# How to identify if a new component is being added to a managed package upo upload

Tags: managed-package, package, isv, partner

We have a very large managed package that depends on other packages. Every time we want to upload the package we want to make sure that no unnecessary new components are added. As far as I know, the only way to find out is to see if the components being added has its "Included by" or "Available In versions" populated. If not, it means that it is a new component. This is really difficult to check visually now that the package has grown. Any ideas on how to check for new components being included in the package before upload without going through this?

Comment: Source control? Even with that your best answer will come from what you are already doing. (Currently)

Comment: Source control doesn't show what is in the package. It show what is in the org. We may have a component in the org but not added to the package.

Comment: You will have to check visually only.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted the whole page into an excel spreadsheet. If the fourth column in front of a component is empty, it is a new component. This takes minutes down to seconds!